# Reparent a Main branch of Team Project -A, to other Team project- B, in same collection

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

TFS- Project Main - code want to move to other Project with out losing the Changset history, checkin history and data, to use as like.

is there is any way to do this, am using Reparent TFS.

Reparent main branch to project -A to Project -B, as all the changset history, checkin history will has to remain same....

Could you please guide me on this....

Thanks in Adv

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot migrate source code between Team Projects while retaining history.

Comment: Can we use tf baseless merge

Comment: No; source code in one team project belongs to that team project and that team project alone. You cannot merge or otherwise operate across them. It sounds like you shouldn't be putting your code in separate team projects in the first place.

Comment: Actually, in project A, some website code is there previously using, in proj B - new website code is there, we need to merge or copy proj - A to Proj -B with out losing any changeset history, check in history ...etc... in Proj -A`s website web changset data .... , is there any approach  like TFS reparent ... like this any ?